# Are there any free GeoIP services which are accurate to detect whether 2 addresses are within 6Km?

Tags: geolocation, gps, distance, geoip, maxmind

I have to make a restaurant home delivery website, and the owners do not wish to deliver more than 6km away.  I hear that the geoIP DB 'Maxmind GeoLite city' is not particularly accurate though. Furthermore if you know of a database that has a shortcode, or predefined query for obtaining the distance without loads of coding, I would love to hear about it! I hope the question is well defined enough. All advice welcome!

Comment: SQL Server 2012 has a datatype called geography. Look at the extended references. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the specification of your project, but it's likely you do know the delivery address. In this case you could use Google's Geocoding APIs to get the position (lat,lng) and then calculate the distance.

Of course there are limitations in the amount of daily requests, but I hardly think your app will reach that limit.

Take a look here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding

Comment: Good answer! GeoIP is not accurate because IP adresses change all the time. But reverse geocoding (street address to geo coords) gives pretty amazing results and you'll very likely get results accurate within a 100m or so. It's also simpler because getting the client IP can be tricky when the server is behind a proxy/loadbalancer etc.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no free IP geolocation databases that will reliably provide the accuracy you are looking for, especially if your client has visitors using mobile devices.

I would recommend that you take a look at [W3C Geolocation JavaScript API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). The results from this will often be more accurate than IP geolocation, especially if the user is on a device with GPS. Do note that it will pop up a dialog asking the user whether they want to share their location with your site.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 geo location if far more accurate than IP address based location.

http://ipgeo5.com/

Comment: This site give me the wrong city, not accurate at all.